# what is xhr.send in this code what works?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, send

hello every i have  a question in this code im not understand what is xhr.send() work?
becuas its down of my code and im hanging

```
document.querySelector('.get-jokes').addEventListener('click', getJokes);

function getJokes(e) {
    const number = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]').value;

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', `http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/${number}`, true);

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            let output = '';

            if (response.type === 'success') {
                response.value.forEach(function(joke) {
                    output += `<li>${joke.joke}</li>`;
                });
            } else {
                output += '<li>Something went wrong</li>';
            }

            document.querySelector('.jokes').innerHTML = output;
        }
    }

    xhr.send();

    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Did you see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)?

Answer (score 0):

xhr is an instance of XMLHttpRequest. The send() method of XMLHttpRequest sends the request to the server. If the request is asynchronous, it returns as soon as the request is sent and the result is delivered using events. In the synchronous case, this method does not return until the response has arrived.

Further details, go through this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)